# How to change Number of Columns of SwiftUI NavigationView depending on Selected SideBar Item?

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, navigation, ipados

I am currently working with the `SwiftUI` `NavigationView` on the `iPad`.

**Problem:** Obviously `iPadOS` supports `2 or 3 columns NavigationViews`. However, I have to declare the `number of Columns` when initializing the NavigationView without any chance of changing this later.

**My Idea** *(Does not work)*:

```swift
@State var selection: NavigationItem? = .first

NavigationView {
    sidebar

    Text("Select an Option in the left Sidebar.")

    if (selection == .first) {
        Text("Choose an Element to preview it here.")
    }
}
```

> The NavigationView on the iPad will always be a `3 Columns One`, although I only pass the third Text when the `Selection == .first`.

[image: Screenshot of the iPad Screen]

**Question:** How can I accomplish the Goal of having a `NavigationView`, which `Number of Columns` depend on the selected `Option` in the `Sidebar`. For Example, when selecting the `First Option`, I would like to have a `3 Column NavigationView` while having a `2 Column One` when the `Second Option` is selected?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @Viraf not really